# Trying to get the number of tries to start at 1 and not 0

Tags: python

Whenever you run the game and start guessing it asks first what is guess #0? I'm trying to get it to display "what is guess #1?" but. at the same time keep the number of guesses equal to the number guessed (if that makes sense). Here's my code so far:

```
import random

def play_game(name, lower=1, upper=10):
    secret = random.randint(lower, upper)
    tries = 0

    print("-----------------------------\n"
          "Welcome, {}!\n"
          "I am thinking of a number\n"
          "between {} and {}.\n"
          "Let's see how many times it\n"
          "will take you to guess!\n"
          "-----------------------------".format(name, lower, upper))

    # Main loop
    guessing_numbers = True
    while guessing_numbers:
        guess = input("What is guess #{}?\n".format(tries))


        while not guess.isdigit():
            print("[!] Sorry, that isn't a valid input.\n"
                  "[!] Please only enter numbers.\n")
            guess = input("What is guess #{}?\n".format(tries))

        guess = int(guess)
        tries += 1

        if guess < secret:
            print("Too low. Try again!")
        elif guess > secret:
            print("Too high. Try again!")
        else:
            guessing_numbers = False

    if tries == 1:
        guess_form = "guess"
    else:
        guess_form = "guesses"

    print("--------------------------\n"
          "Congratulations, {}!\n"
          "You got it in {} {}!\n"
          "--------------------------\n".format(name,tries,guess_form))

    if tries < 3:
        # Randomly chooses from an item in the list
        tries_3 = ["Awesome job!","Bravo!","You rock!"]
        print (random.choice(tries_3))
        # ---
    elif tries < 5:
        tries_5 = ["Hmmmmmpff...","Better luck next time.","Ohhh c'mon!     You can do better than that."]
        print (random.choice(tries_5))
    elif tries < 7:
        tries_7 = ["You better find something else to do..","You can do better!","Maybe next time..."]
        print (random.choice(tries_7))
    else:
        tries_8 = ["You should be embarrassed!","My dog could do better. Smh...","Even I can do better.."]
        print (random.choice(tries_8))

    choice = input("Would you like to play again? Y/N?\n")
    if "y" in choice.lower():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main():
    name = input("What is your name?\n")
    playing = True
    while playing:
        playing = play_game(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have the number of "tries" set to 0 at the beginning. However, if I set that to 1 then play the game and it only takes me 3 tries it will display that it took me 4 tries. so I'm not sure what to do. Still somewhat new to python so I would love some help

Comment: Well, why not just change how you display it? `.format(tries + 1)`

Comment: that works. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere that you have `input("What is guess #{}?\n".format(tries))`, use `guess = input("What is guess #{}?\n".format(tries+1))`. (adding +1 to tries in the expression, but not changing the variable itself)